# Where do you put the Oracle's JDBC Thin Driver for Crystal Reports?

Tags: java, jdbc, crystal-reports

Where do you save the jdbc thin driver for Oracle?  I have tried `jre/lib/ext` but my program, Crystal Reports keeps saying it can't find it. I figure I have saved it in the wrong place.

If I go to a command prompt and use:

> C:\TEMP>java oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
>
> Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Fri_Aug_26_08:19:15_PDT_2011
> Default Connection Properties Resource
> Wed Oct 12 14:02:05 EDT 2011

So I know it is there.

edit:  Since I could not get CR to work I tried a console app but it cannot find the driver:

```
package javaapplication1;


public class JavaApplication1 {

 public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:mysid", "myid", "mypass");
                        // @//machineName:port/SID,   userid,  password
   try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     try {
       ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select BANNER from SYS.V_$VERSION");
       try {
         while (rset.next())
           System.out.println (rset.getString(1));   // Print col 1
       } 
       finally {
          try { rset.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
       }
     } 
     finally {
       try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
     }
   } 
   finally {
     try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
  }
}
```

edit:  On my computer it is here:

C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\jdk\jre\lib\ext

Comment: your application should have a preferences window (or config file) in which you can configure the path for external jars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in the application's runtime classpath. The file system paths covererd by the classpath depends on how you're executing the application.

Based on your question history I see that you're using JSP/Servlets, which thus means that it's a web application in flavor of a WAR file which runs in an appserver. In that case, the JAR file needs to go in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` folder or in the appserver's own `/lib` folder.

If it were a plain vanilla Java application `.class` file with a `main()` method which is to be executed by `java` command, then you'd have to use the `-cp` (`-classpath`) argument to specify the runtime classpath. It takes a collection of (semi)colon separated disk file system paths.

If it were a JAR file, then it had to be specified in the `Class-Path` entry in JAR's `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. This can be relative to the `java -jar` command's working directory.

You should really avoid putting 3rd party libraries in JRE's `/lib` folder. This would potentially introduce classpath problems with all other existing applications which use the same JRE.

Comment: Right now I'm just trying a regular old java console app.  I was trying CR, but since that failed I'm trying the console app.

Comment: Use the `-cp` argument to specify the classpath including the location of the JAR file. Something like `java -cp .;/path/to/filename.jar com.example.YourClass`. In Windows, the classpath paths are to be separated with semicolon `;`. The `.` indicates the current directory (so that `YourClass` can be found).

Comment: I thought that was what the classpath variable was for in windows.

Comment: You're talking about the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable? Yes, that can also, but this is **ignored** whenever you use `-cp`, `-classpath` or `-jar` arguments. Also, it's considered a poor practice as it may introduce potential classpath problems with all other existing applications. I suggest to remove `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable and forget about it. If you get tired of typing `-cp` everytime, just put the entire `java` command in a `.bat` file and execute it instead.