# Fatal Error has been detected by java runtime environment.... cannot understand why?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, oracle10g

My code is given below. Its a program that adds leaves to the database.I am getting the Fatal Error has been detected by java runtime environment and I am not understanding why. I am new to Java, so I am very confused about this. Can anybody tell me why is this happening?
I am putting up the error file as well. I tried understanding that too but couldn't find where is the error located.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class AddLeave extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel,panel1;
JLabel empid,name1,name2,department,designation;
JTextField txtempid,txtname1,txtname2,txtdepartment,txtdesignation;
JButton find,ok,cancel;
String txtname1_1 = "";
String  txtname2_1 = "";
String  txtdepartment_1 = "";
String  txtdesignation_1 = "";
String  txtempid1="";   
Connection conn;

public AddLeave()
{
    frame=new JFrame("ADD LEAVE");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,5,5));
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    panel1=new JPanel();
    //panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3,10,10));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    empid=new JLabel("Employee Id:");
    name1=new JLabel("First Name:");
    name2=new JLabel("Last Name:");
    department=new JLabel("Department:");
    designation=new JLabel("Designation:");

    txtempid = new JTextField();
    txtname1 = new JTextField();
    txtname1.setEditable(false);
    txtname2 = new JTextField();
    txtname2.setEditable(false);
    txtdepartment = new JTextField();
    txtdesignation = new JTextField();
    txtdesignation.setEditable(false);

    find=new JButton("FIND");
    find.addActionListener(this);
    ok=new JButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(this);
    cancel=new JButton("CANCEL");
    cancel.addActionListener(this);


    panel.add(empid);
    panel.add(txtempid);
    panel.add(name1);
    panel.add(txtname1);
    panel.add(name2);
    panel.add(txtname2);
    panel.add(department);
    panel.add(txtdepartment);
    panel.add(designation);
    panel.add(txtdesignation);

    panel1.add(find);
    panel1.add(ok);
    panel1.add(cancel);

    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    connect();
}

public void connect()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:demo","system","scott");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Error : "+e);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    Object source= event.getSource();
    if(source.equals(find))
    {
        find();
    }

    if(source.equals(ok))
    {
        System.out.println("Leave added");
    }
    if(source.equals(cancel))
    {
        System.out.println("Canceled");
    }
}

public void find()
{

    txtempid1=txtempid.getText();
    try
    {

        if(txtempid1.isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID REQUIRED!!!","warning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        }
        else
        {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE empid='"+txtempid1+"'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int foundrec = 0;
            while (rs.next())
            {
                        txtname1_1 = rs.getString(2);
                txtname2_1 = rs.getString(3);
                txtdesignation_1 = rs.getString(4); 
                foundrec =foundrec+ 1;
            }
            if(foundrec==1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"**Record Found**"," Message",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                txtname1.setText(txtname1_1);
                txtname2.setText(txtname2_1); 
                txtdesignation.setText(txtdesignation_1); 

            }
            else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"!!!!EMPLOYEE DOES NOT EXIST!!!!"," ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        conn.close();   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error : "+e);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new AddLeave();
}
}
```

this is the error file

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c901010, pid=3052, tid=3732
    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_31-b05
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [ntdll.dll+0x1010]
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x03054400):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native,     id=3732, stack(0x03250000,0x032a0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000018

    Registers:
    EAX=0x00000004, EBX=0x329ab298, ECX=0x7ffad000, EDX=0x00000004
    ESP=0x0329ea48, EBP=0x0329ea60, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x03401590
    EIP=0x7c901010, EFLAGS=0x00010246

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x0329ea48)
    0x0329ea48:   74355a16 00000004 034015b4 7432139f
    0x0329ea58:   034015b4 03401590 0329ea70 74322c5d
    0x0329ea68:   034015b4 03054528 0329ea84 74325fa0
    0x0329ea78:   03401590 74350000 0329f1ac 0329eaa0
    0x0329ea88:   7432740e 03401590 0329eac0 00000003
    0x0329ea98:   0312cd28 03054528 0329eab8 6d36124e
    0x0329eaa8:   03401590 0329eac0 03054400 329ab298
    0x0329eab8:   0329eb04 00919fc7 00000000 0329eb20 

    Instructions: (pc=0x7c901010)
    0x7c900ff0:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    0x7c901000:   90 90 90 90 90 64 8b 0d 18 00 00 00 8b 54 24 04
    0x7c901010:   83 7a 14 00 75 4f f0 ff 42 04 75 19 8b 41 24 89
    0x7c901020:   42 0c c7 42 08 01 00 00 00 33 c0 c2 04 00 8d a4 


    Register to memory mapping:

    EAX=0x00000004 is an unknown value
    EBX=0x329ab298 is an oop
    {method} 
     - klass: {other class}
    ECX=0x7ffad000 is an unknown value
    EDX=0x00000004 is an unknown value
    ESP=0x0329ea48 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x03054400
    EBP=0x0329ea60 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x03054400
    ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
    EDI=0x03401590 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x03250000,0x032a0000],  sp=0x0329ea48,  free space=314k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [ntdll.dll+0x1010]  RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xb
    C  [ODBC32.dll+0x2c5d]  MpHeapAlloc+0x452
    C  [ODBC32.dll+0x5fa0]  SQLSetStmtAttrW+0xfeb
    C  [ODBC32.dll+0x740e]  SQLAllocStmt+0x21
    C  [JdbcOdbc.dll+0x124e]  Java_sun_jdbc_odbc_JdbcOdbc_allocStmt+0x28
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.allocStmt(J[B)J+0
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLAllocStmt(J)J+47
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement(II)Ljava/sql/Statement;+27
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement()Ljava/sql/Statement;+7
    j  AddLeave.find()V+37
    j  AddLeave.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+17
    j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+84
    j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
    j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+35
    j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117
    j     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35
    j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64
    j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
    j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
    j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+570
    j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
    j   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/Mous eEvent;)V+320
    j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+139
    j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
    j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
    j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+65
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$1.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x18c3a1]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xbb654]
    C  [java.dll+0x102f]     Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2+0x17
    j   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedActio n;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Objec t;+28
    j   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedActio n;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x18c3a1]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xbb654]
    C  [java.dll+0x102f]              Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2Ljava_se curity_AccessControlContext_2+0x17
    j    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+73
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+204
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
    j   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x18c3a1]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfade1]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xfae3b]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xb5569]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x118f14]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x140ffc]
    C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
    C  [kernel32.dll+0xb50b]  GetModuleFileNameA+0x1b4

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.allocStmt(J[B)J+0
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLAllocStmt(J)J+47
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement(II)Ljava/sql/Statement;+27
    j  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.createStatement()Ljava/sql/Statement;+7
    j  AddLeave.find()V+37
    j  AddLeave.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+17
    j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+84
    j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5
    j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+35
    j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117
    j   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35
    j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64
    j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23
    j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
    j  java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+18
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+570
    j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
    j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+320
    j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+139
    j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50
    j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+12
    j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+65
    j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$1.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/ AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
    j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
    j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
    j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+73
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+204
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
    j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x0312dc00 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3508,   stack(0x03540000,0x03590000)]
      0x002a6400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3588, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]
     0x0308f400 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x03370000,0x033c0000)]
    =>0x03054400 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=3732,  stack(0x03250000,0x032a0000)]
      0x02b8f800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=380, stack(0x02f90000,0x02fe0000)]
      0x02b8e400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3368, stack(0x02f40000,0x02f90000)]
      0x02b8cc00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=972, stack(0x02ef0000,0x02f40000)]
      0x02b48800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1524, stack(0x02dc0000,0x02e10000)]
      0x02b43400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3272, stack(0x02d70000,0x02dc0000)]
      0x02b41000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1364, stack(0x02d20000,0x02d70000)]
      0x02b3f800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2804, stack(0x02cd0000,0x02d20000)]
      0x02b38400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3164, stack(0x02c80000,0x02cd0000)]
      0x02b36c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1656, stack(0x02c30000,0x02c80000)]

     Other Threads:
      0x02afa000 VMThread [stack: 0x02be0000,0x02c30000] [id=1988]
      0x02b4b400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e10000,0x02e60000] [id=956]

     VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

     VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

     Heap
    def new generation   total 4928K, used 2084K [0x22970000, 0x22ec0000, 0x27ec0000)
    eden space 4416K,  47% used [0x22970000, 0x22b791d8, 0x22dc0000)
    from space 512K,   0% used [0x22dc0000, 0x22dc0000, 0x22e40000)
     to   space 512K,   0% used [0x22e40000, 0x22e40000, 0x22ec0000)
    tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x27ec0000, 0x28970000, 0x32970000)
     the space 10944K,   0% used [0x27ec0000, 0x27ec0000, 0x27ec0200, 0x28970000)
     compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 764K [0x32970000, 0x33570000, 0x36970000)
     the space 12288K,   6% used [0x32970000, 0x32a2f0f0, 0x32a2f200, 0x33570000)
     ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x36970000, 0x36e9e318, 0x36e9e400, 0x37370000)
     rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x37370000, 0x37a0a088, 0x37a0a200, 0x37f70000)

    Code Cache  [0x00910000, 0x009b0000, 0x02910000)
     total_blobs=316 nmethods=92 adapters=160 free_code_cache=32927040 largest_free_block=0

    Dynamic libraries:
    0x00400000 - 0x00425000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe
    0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
    0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
    0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    0x77e70000 - 0x77f01000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
    0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
    0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
    0x77d40000 - 0x77dd0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
     0x77f10000 - 0x77f56000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
    0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
    0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
    0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
    0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
    0x6d000000 - 0x6d14c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
     0x73000000 - 0x73026000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
    0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
    0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
    0x774e0000 - 0x7761c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
    0x773d0000 - 0x774d2000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-  Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2180_x-ww_a84f1ff9\COMCTL32.dll
    0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
    0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
    0x6d230000 - 0x6d27f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
    0x74720000 - 0x7476b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
    0x4fdd0000 - 0x4ff76000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
    0x03020000 - 0x03026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
    0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
    0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
    0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
    0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
     0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
    0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
    0x77120000 - 0x771ac000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
    0x6d360000 - 0x6d36d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\JdbcOdbc.dll
    0x74320000 - 0x7435d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ODBC32.dll
    0x763b0000 - 0x763f9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
    0x20000000 - 0x20017000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\odbcint.dll
    0x032e0000 - 0x032e5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msorc32r.dll
    0x10000000 - 0x10061000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oci.dll
    0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
    0x61c20000 - 0x61e73000      C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\ORACLIENT10.DLL
     0x60870000 - 0x60956000    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oracore10.dll
     0x60a80000 - 0x60b46000    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranls10.dll
    0x63690000 - 0x636a8000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraunls10.dll
    0x60eb0000 - 0x60eb7000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orauts.dll
    0x636b0000 - 0x636b6000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oravsn10.dll
     0x60fa0000 - 0x61092000    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oracommon10.dll
    0x60300000 - 0x60858000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orageneric10.dll
    0x63430000 - 0x63457000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orasnls10.dll
    0x035a0000 - 0x0372c000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraxml10.dll
    0x03730000 - 0x03741000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCIRT.dll
    0x60960000 - 0x60a6d000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oran10.dll
    0x62740000 - 0x6277d000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranl10.dll
    0x62790000 - 0x627a7000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranldap10.dll
    0x627f0000 - 0x628f9000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orannzsbb10.dll
    0x62530000 - 0x62583000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraldapclnt10.dll
    0x62670000 - 0x6268b000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orancrypt10.dll
    0x71ad0000 - 0x71ad9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
    0x62920000 - 0x6296c000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranro10.dll
    0x626b0000 - 0x626b7000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranhost10.dll
    0x62660000 - 0x62666000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orancds10.dll
    0x629c0000 - 0x629c8000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orantns10.dll
    0x60b50000 - 0x60ea9000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orapls10.dll
    0x63420000 - 0x63429000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraslax10.dll
    0x63080000 - 0x63284000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraplp10.dll
    0x61ed0000 - 0x61f5b000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orahasgen10.dll
    0x62ab0000 - 0x62b1a000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraocr10.dll
    0x62b20000 - 0x62b60000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oraocrb10.dll
    0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
    0x62980000 - 0x62990000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orantcp10.dll
    0x63520000 - 0x635ba000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\orasql10.dll
    0x5fe80000 - 0x5fe9b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\odbccp32.dll
    0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
    0x62650000 - 0x62659000     C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\oranbeq10.dll
    0x71f80000 - 0x71f84000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\security.dll
    0x77c70000 - 0x77c93000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msv1_0.dll
     0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll

    VM Arguments:
     java_command: AddLeave
     Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

     Environment Variables:
     CLASSPATH=.
   PATH=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WIN    DOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Common       Files\Nero\Lib\
    USERNAME=sunanda
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel


    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

     OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 2

     CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov,  cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

    Memory: 4k page, physical 1045684k(346004k free), swap 2517544k(1203440k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_31-b05),  built on Feb  3 2012 18:44:09 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

    time: Sun Apr 08 15:46:59 2012
    elapsed time: 9 seconds
```

"Demo"  is the name of the database which has 4 columns namely empid,Fname,Lname,designation. The working of the program is that when I enter the employee ID it retrieves the remaining data from the database. As I have not added the department Id column I am not getting that from the database.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%2BEXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION+%2Bntdll.dll+%2Bjre&submit=search

Answer (score 1):

I usually see these errors when something went wrong in the JNI (*Java Native Interface*) code, i.e. here, perhaps the JDBC (*Java DataBase Connectivity*) driver `ODBC32.dll`. Are you sure you are using correct version of the JDBC driver for your platform? Especially check you are using 32-bit version on a 32-bit OS (*Operating System*) and not a 64-bit version (or vice-versa).

`The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.`

Comment: Can you please tell me how should I find out the JDBC driver version?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g and jdk 1.6.

Comment: For example, try to download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html (I guess, you already figured it).

Comment: I am trying to search that... but I have a doubt. The drivers class12.jar is for 10g but says that it is for jdk 1.4 & 1.5 where as I have jdk 1.6. I also saw the 11g drivers ojdbc6.jar here(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-111060-084321.html).So I am confused about whether I should download 11g and that driver or just the class12.jar one.

Comment: I believe it is not a problem to use the JDK 1.5 JDBC driver with JDK 1.6 (the other way around it would be a problem).

Comment: I have downloaded the class12.jar for Oracle 10.2.0.1 version. But I dont know what I should do with it or how I should install it. I read here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744329/where-do-you-put-the-oracles-jdbc-thin-driver-for-crystal-reports) that we have to add it to the java classpath but exactly how I dint get that.

Comment: Does it mean that we have to change the classpath in environment variables from a dot(.) to something else? For that also I'll need to exactly where I should place the jar file so that I can add that path to the classpath variable.

Comment: Yes, it does. I presume you are on Windows, so use something like `java -cp .;oracle-jdbc.jar AddLeave`. That adds the downloaded JAR file to the program classpath.

Comment: The program is actually working the first time but giving the same result again when I do it the second time. I added the path for the jar file in the CLASSPATH also but its giving same results(working once only).

Comment: I am sorry, but this seems as some other problem than the topic of this question. If the question is solved, you should close it. If you have some other problem start a new question with a new description. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [Oracle JDBC Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) appropriate for your Oracle database version; these are typically pure Java. The [JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html) has significant limitations, including JNI dependency.

Comment: actually when I checked C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib this path i had ojdbc14 and ojdbc14_g in the lib folder.These are pure drivers right? I saw them on the oracle website. So why do I need another pure driver?

Comment: Right, but it looks like the ODBC driver is getting used instead. You'll have to hunt it down; `java -verbose` may shed light.